# Labels on the left side of my input fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying for a long time to get my labels on the left side on my input fields. I'm banging my head against the wall. I use a font-awesome icon in the label.

[image: label with input field]

I tried a lot of searches on Google and Stack Overflow and tried stuff like inline-block which I see should work but it didn't work for me. My code so far. I guess it's an easy fix for all the great people that are here.

```css
.wrapperAddSnippet {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 10px 0 25px 80px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet input[type="text"] {
    width: 310px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapperAddSnippet">
        <form action="includes/addSnippet.inc.php" method="get">
            <div class="wrapperSnippet">
                    <label for="snippetTitle"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetTitle" name="snippetTitle" placeholder="Title">
                    <label for="snippetCat"><i class="fas fa-layer-group"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetCat" name="snippetCat" placeholder="Snippet category">
                    <label for="snippetDesc"><i class="fas fa-i-cursor"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetDesc" name="snippetDesc" placeholder="Snippet description">
                    <label for="snippetURL"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetURL" name="snippetURL" placeholder="Snippet URL">
                    <label for="snippetImage"><i class="fas fa-image"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetImage" name="snippetImage" placeholder="snippet Image">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Save Snippet</button>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapperSnippet">
                    <label  for="snippet"><i class="fas fa-code"></i></label>
                    <textarea id="snippet" name="snippet" placeholder="Snippet"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method, in my opinion, is to turn `.wrapperSnippet` into a CSS Grid layout.

[Grid is supported by all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid) but IE supports an older version of the spec.

We can define the grid with two columns: one of width `auto`, and the other with `1fr`. `auto` means that it will take up as much space as needed to fit the element, then the `1fr` will fill the remaining space.

```css
/* Added style */

.wrapperSnippet {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

/* Styles from question snippet */

.wrapperAddSnippet {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 10px 0 25px 80px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3274d6;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet input[type="text"] {
    width: 310px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.wrapperAddSnippet textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapperAddSnippet">
        <form action="includes/addSnippet.inc.php" method="get">
            <div class="wrapperSnippet">
                    <label for="snippetTitle"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetTitle" name="snippetTitle" placeholder="Title">
                    <label for="snippetCat"><i class="fas fa-layer-group"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetCat" name="snippetCat" placeholder="Snippet category">
                    <label for="snippetDesc"><i class="fas fa-i-cursor"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetDesc" name="snippetDesc" placeholder="Snippet description">
                    <label for="snippetURL"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetURL" name="snippetURL" placeholder="Snippet URL">
                    <label for="snippetImage"><i class="fas fa-image"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" id="snippetImage" name="snippetImage" placeholder="snippet Image">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Save Snippet</button>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapperSnippet">
                    <label  for="snippet"><i class="fas fa-code"></i></label>
                    <textarea id="snippet" name="snippet" placeholder="Snippet"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, the grid solution seems to work ok, did some other tweaks and it's looking ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some CSS-style properties and added some properties. Use these styles instead. May be helpful.

```
<style>

    .wrapperAddSnippet {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 10px 0 25px 80px;
    }
    
    .wrapperAddSnippet form {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .wrapperAddSnippet label {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #3274d6;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .wrapperAddSnippet input[type="text"] {
        display: block;
        width: 310px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    
    .wrapperAddSnippet textarea {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }

</style>
```